# Jedi doesn't work properly with PyQt5

Tags: python, auto-complete-mode, jedi

I have `auto-complete` and `jedi` installed and everything works just fine except autocompletion in PyQt5. When i try to subclass for example `QWidget` and in the `__init__` method I type `self` and then press dot on my keyboard which triggers autocompletion popup it gives me an error:

```
deffered error : (error "RuntimeError('generator raised StopIteration')")
```

When I issue command `jedi:pop-to-epc-buffer` I see a number **56977** and repeated error message.

Here's my emacs config reffered to `jedi`:

```
(use-package jedi
  :ensure t
  :init
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup))

(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
```

Any ideas what causes this error?

#### EDIT:

This is sample code (# is the position of cursor):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.#
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of code that's causing your problem (I'm talking about relevant `import`s and whatnot). This would definitely help people who have experience with this.

Comment: Ok, check **EDIT** section

Comment: Obligatory "did you run Emacs without the init?"  comment.  Run `emacs -q` to load Emacs without the init and then run the elisp you provide.  Does it work then or is it the same problem?

Comment: I did what you said and it still gives me the same error. The only difference is the number after issuing `jedi:pop-to-epc-buffer` which is now **46605** but I guess that it's only some process id or something.